# What is the meaning for let {} =?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between these two lines of code?

```
let { fadeAnim } = this.state;
```

vs

```
let fadeAnim = this.state;?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let { fadeAnim } = this.state;
```

Equals

```
let fadeAnim = this.state.fadeAnim;
```

It’s called destructuring assignment: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operatoren/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 0):

If `this.state` is a reference to an object, then

```
let { fadeAnim } = this.state;
```

is like

```
let fadeAnim = this.state.fadeAnim;
```

It's a *destructuring* assignment that implicitly extracts one or more properties from an object (just one in this case).